# Rename qcow2 internal snapshots created with virsh snapshot-create-as

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, libvirt, virsh

### Background

I have a QEMU/KVM virtual machine whose virtual disk is a qcow2 file. To create snapshots, I have been using

```
sudo virsh snapshot-create-as <vm_name> <snapshot_name>
```

and now I can display them using, for example, `virsh snapshot-list --tree`:

```
$ sudo virsh snapshot-list --tree my_vm
snapshot_001
  |
  +- snapshot_002
      |
      +- snapshot_003
```

I want to rename these snapshots (e.g. from `snapshot_00X` to `my_snapshot_00X`), but there is no `virsh snapshot-rename` command. Both of the possible workarounds I can think of seem to have serious pitfalls, and I would be glad to know if there is a better one.

#### Workaround 1

I could do, for each snapshot that I want to rename:

```
sudo snapshot-edit <vm_name> <snapshot_name> --rename
```

and then edit contents of the `<name>` element in the resulting XML.

However, [`man virsh`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/libvirt-clients/virsh.1.en.html) seems to warn strongly against this (my emphasis):

> Note that changing a snapshot name must be done with care, since the contents of some snapshots, such as **internal snapshots within a single qcow2 file**, are accessible only from the original name.

Because the snapshots, in my case are indeed internal snapshots within a single qcow2 file, it sounds as though using `virsh snapshot-edit` could render them inaccessible.

#### Workaround 2

I could, I suppose, use `qemu-img` to convert the internal snapshots into external snapshots plus a backing file, and then rename them, and then recombine them into internal snapshots of a single qcow2 file.

But this is non-trivial, and would also require manually editing the VM to restore my ability to use commands like `virsh snapshot-revert` (without which, the snapshots are effectively useless). I would be very surprised if there is not a better way.

### Question

Compared to the workarounds given above, is there a better way to rename a series of QEMU/KVM internal qcow2 snapshots that have been created with `virsh snapshot-create-as`, without losing the ability to run them via `virsh snapshot-revert`?